# Make modal appear once [cookie consent]

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage

I currently have this code set up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#modal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Privacy Policy</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I have no idea how to set up cookies etc, I am wondering how to make this modal appear once per user, obviously it would appear again if they clear their cookies but how can I do this?

/T

Comment: Check this library which will make it very straight forward: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: you can't do it without hurting privacy, i assume.

Comment: Yeah you can, you must do it, most websites are doing it these days with GDPR in action.

Answer (score 0):

IF there is no specific requirement to use [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie), you can do this using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as well. I think which is simple and straight forward.

Comment: I don't get it :/